# R xml2 error: Start tag expected, '<' not found [4]

Tags: r, xml, xml2

I am trying to import an XML file from a URL:

```r
library(xml2)

x <- read_xml('https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/GTR/data/gtr_ftp.xml.gz')
Error in read_xml.raw(raw, encoding = encoding, base_url = base_url, as_html = as_html,  : 
  Start tag expected, '<' not found [4]
```

According to the documentation I should be able to pass a URL for a .gz file and it will be uncompressed. If I download the file, unzip it locally, and then use `read_xml` it works fine. This is a pretty large file (~ 2 GB unzipped) and so I am not sure if that is a problem over a connection. Any thoughts on how I can read this directly from a connection?

Comment: I downloaded the file externally (saved to a file), uncompressed it externally (`gunzip` in a shell), then loaded using `read_xml("gtr_ftp.xml")`, all without error, and the resulting `x` is `c("xml_document", "xml_node")`. Perhaps it was a network glitch (corrupting the `.gz` file), or something in `read_xml`'s implementation of working with the compressed file did something amiss. Try the manual steps to get your data.

Comment: @r2evans thanks -- yes, I can get it to work manually, just wondering if there is a way to do it through a connection since the data update somewhat regularly. Do you get the same error when trying to pull it from the posted code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The catch is that the documentation says "**Local** paths ending in .gz, .bz2, .xz, .zip will be automatically uncompressed" (emphasis added). The logic seems to be in the `xml2:::path_to_connection` function. URLs are not automatically uncompressed, only local files on disc.

The `read_xml` function will use the `curl` package to work with URLs if installed. If you have that package, you can wrap the download call with `gzcon` to do the decoding. Assuming you have enough RAM, you could try

```
x <- read_xml(gzcon(curl::curl(url)))
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [xml2 documentation](https://xml2.r-lib.org/index.html), [`read_xml()'s`](https://xml2.r-lib.org/reference/read_xml.html) argument can be

> A string can be either a path, a url or literal xml. Urls will be converted into connections either using `base::url` or, if installed, `curl::curl`. ***Local paths* ending in `.gz`, `.bz2`, `.xz`, `.zip` will be automatically uncompressed.** [emphasis added]

The argument in your failing case is a *remote* compressed file.